# How to install packages from a list in different distros?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install a list of packages from `pkglist.txt` at least in Manjaro and Ubuntu although if there is a way to install on all distros it would be better. How can I do this?

I've thought of something like:

```
# If on Manjaro:
yay -S --no-confirm --needed - < pkglist.txt
# Else if on Ubuntu:
xargs sudo apt install < pkglist.txt
```

The problem is that I get a bunch of `Unable to locate package` errors. I could install the packages one by one from the file and ignore the errors.

Comment: Packages may have different names or may be structured in a different way on different distributions. It might be better to use a separate list for every distribution. How did you create the list of packages? Where did you find the package names? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically boils down to "different distros are different": It's not possible in general. You'll need to maintain a list of package names for both distros.

There's a few tricks to still automate:

- Most distros allow you to ask the package repository which packages provide a specific file – for example, if you know the thing will be called `/usr/bin/oocalc`, you can use `apt-file search /usr/bin/oocalc` to find the package on debian, ubuntu etc, the same works with `dnf repoquery --whatprovides` on Fedora/RHEL-oids, and I'm sure Arch/Manjaro have similar tools. This all breaks down, quickly, though, because different distros can put files at different locations. Some distros, for example, use an architecture prefix. Also, there might be multiple packages providing the same file. (E.g., different versions of the same program, or community vs upstream package etc; see mariadb/mysql for an example of that)
- You can of course try to automatedly guess from package name and fuzzily match the best possible package. Good luck! You usually won't get a 100% success rate
- Since this sounds like you want to automate setting up machines, maybe just using ansible roles that someone else maintains (and thus, someone else maintains the "what is the package installing this software?" list) would solve multiple problems at once.